# Angular: cannot read property of undefined but still displays data

Tags: angular

I'm quite confused because my application is displaying necessary data, but there are still errors in the console that I would like to get rid of.

Typescript:

```
  activeClient: Client;

  constructor(private clientService: ClientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inViewMode = true;
    this.clientId = parseInt(window.location.pathname.split('/')[2], 10);
    this.clientService.getClientById(this.clientId)
        .subscribe(data => this.activeClient = data);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="form-group col-12">
       <label for="name">Ettevõtte nimi<span *ngIf="!inViewMode" class="required">*</span></label>
       <input class="form-control" id="name" [value]="activeClient.companyName">
   </div>
</div>
```

Client model:

```
export interface Client {
    id?: number;
    companyName?: String;
    firmRegNo?: number;
    address?: String;
    clientName?: String;
    phoneOne?: number;
    phoneTwo?: number;
    email?: String;
    explanation?: String;
    rating?: number;
    status?: String;
    clientContract?: ClientContract;
}
```

Comment: where are the exact errors?

Comment: That's because you haven't initialized your variable. Can you show the structure of `Client`?

Comment: Cannot read property 'companyName' of undefined.

Comment: @Arcteezy Updated thread

Comment: It's a good practice to use safe traversal in your HTML as - `activeClient?.companyName` or `activeClient['companyName']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) to prevent the error until `activeClient` is initialized:

```
[value]="activeClient?.companyName"
```

Comment: This did the trick. I'm guessing the errors were displayd before the HTTP request went through and provided data to activeClient, right?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the value for the `activeClient` by making an `async` call to an API. Your template won't wait untill that gets defined. And hence you're getting this error on the console.

As soon as the `activeClient` is initialized in the `subscribe` block, you do see the value.

To avoid that, don't render the template untill the `activeClient` is initialized.

Since `activeClient` has a lot of fields, I'd recommend using `*ngIf`:

```
<div class="form-row" *ngIf="activeClient">
   <div class="form-group col-12">
       <label for="name">Ettevõtte nimi<span *ngIf="!inViewMode" class="required">*</span></label>
       <input class="form-control" id="name" [value]="activeClient.companyName">
   </div>
</div>
```

### Optionally, you could also use an `async` pipe in the template:

```
activeClient$: Observable<Client>;

constructor(private clientService: ClientService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.inViewMode = true;
  this.clientId = parseInt(window.location.pathname.split('/')[2], 10);
  this.activeClient$ = this.clientService.getClientById(this.clientId);
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div class="form-row" *ngIf="activeClient$ | async as activeClient">
   <div class="form-group col-12">
       <label for="name">Ettevõtte nimi<span *ngIf="!inViewMode" class="required">*</span></label>
       <input class="form-control" id="name" [value]="activeClient.companyName">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make the inputs disappear?

Comment: If input is your issue, I think you should have used a Reactive Form. You could then set the form value to the response that you got from the API using the `patchValue` method on a `FormGroup`

Answer (score 2):

By the time the template is rendered, `activeClient` does not exist (waiting for the Observable to pull the data). Use [elvis](https://www.joshmorony.com/safely-displaying-data-with-the-elvis-operator/) operator for safety display.

`[value]="activeClient?.companyName"`